# Perform a liquibase:rollback from the command line when properties are in Spring-boot files (application.properties) and not liquibase.properties

Tags: spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I am using *Spring-boot* with *Liquibase*, and my database configuration is set in an `application.properties` file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/comptesfrance
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/compte-france-postgis-changelog.xml
```

With the help of the maven plugins `liquibase-core` and `liquibase-maven-plugin` everything is working well and my database structure is updated smoothly during the project lifetime.

However, I made a mistake lately in my development environment and I have to use the command line to perform a rollback. Remove a changeset I've just created.

I enter a bash shell and execute :

```sh
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1
```

but it fails with the message : "*The database URL has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file*".

I could set a :

```
<propertyFile>${project.build.directory}/classes/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
```

in the configuration of the `liquibase-maven-plugin` plugin if I had such file... But my properties are in my `application.properties` file instead.

If I attempt to mention this `application.properties` file to *Liquibase*, with a `<propertyFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/application.properties</propertyFile>` configuration, *Liquibase* doesn't recognize its entries :

```
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[INFO]   File: /home/marc/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/DAOPostgis/../ApplicationMetierEtGestion/src/main/resources/application.properties
[INFO]   'spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO]   'spring.datasource.url' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO]   'spring.datasource.password' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO]   'spring.datasource.username' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO]   'spring.jpa.database-platform' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO]   'spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO]   'spring.liquibase.change-log' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO]   'spring.datasource.driver' in properties file is not being used by this task.
```

Is there a way through the `spring-boot:run` commands to issue a rollback ?

It would allow `spring-boot` to send to *Liquibase* the configuration it knows and use well already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property names within springs `application.properties` and `liquidate.properties` are not compatible.
You have three options

1. just create a separate liquibase.properties file with the content
   you need - see  [liquibase doc](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html) as you only need to to fix your
   current setup
2. give the database parameters via command line arguments

   ```
   mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1    -Dliquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/comptesfrance -Dliquibase.username
   ```

   see [rollback goal](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-rollback.html) for all arguments
3. if you need a permanent solution, then you may add the liquibase properties into your `application.properties` and reuse them in the same file. i.e.

   ```
   liquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/comptesfrance
   spring.datasource.url=${liquibase.url}
   ```

   ( I havn't tested this)