# How to fire liquibase rollback script from spring application

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

I am using spring with liquibase to update my database. Since know I have not need to user rollback functonality, but the times come where I would like to make it work.
But I cant seems to fire it from my application.

I know that maven has plugin which helps with that, but until know I was not using it and when I add it I need to provide source and credentials to my database.

In this moment liquibase is configured in xml.

```
<bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="p6spyDataSource"/>
  <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db.changelog-master.yaml"/>
  .
  .
</bean>
```

And in maven I have only dependency to `liquibase-core`.
And the place where I set `liquibase.shouldRun` is in `application.properties`

DataSource is taken from TomEE configuration `server.xml` file

So the question is if I can maybe somehow add maven plugin without adding credentials (should be taken from dataSource). Or is there other way to run rollback script from my changelog?

Answer (score 0):

There are several related questions that have been posted previously about using Liquibase rollback with Spring Boot. This one seems the most similar to your post: [Perform a `liquibase:rollback` from the command line when properties are in Spring-boot files (`application.properties`) and not `liquibase.properties`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299395/perform-a-liquibaserollback-from-the-command-line-when-properties-are-in-spring)

Here is the answer as provided by Robert Kleinschmager:

> The property names within springs application.properties and liquidate.properties are not compatible. You have three options
>
> #1 just create a separate liquibase.properties file with the content you need - see [liquibase doc](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html) as you only need to fix your current setup
> #2 give the database parameters via command-line arguments
>
> ```
> mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1    -Dliquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/comptesfrance -Dliquibase.username
> ```
>
> see [rollback goal](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-rollback.html) for all arguments
>
> #3 if you need a permanent solution, then you may add the liquibase properties into your application.properties and reuse them in the same file. i.e.
>
> ```
> liquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/comptesfrance
> spring.datasource.url=${liquibase.url}
> ```